# How to update the password in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I forgot my password and now unable to reset it.

I tried to update he below file in SD Card  with `init=/bin/sh`

> recovery.cmdline

But when I inserted the SD card in Raspberry Pi again it gave me error and unable to start.

Answer (score 0):

On SD's root folder (/) edit the `cmdline.txt` file. It should contain below line of text:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

You should write `init=/bin/sh` at the end.
Put SD card with edited file to Pi and power it up. Next step is to mount root:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Then run below command for pi user, type desired NEW password:

```
passwd pi
```

Next two more commands:

```
sync
exec /sbin/init
```

Probably the screen will go black, if so, wait few minutes then turn it off.

Last step is to revert changes in `cmdline.txt` file (remove `init=/bin/sh`).
After that put SD card to rPi and log in with NEW password.

Comment: on my SD card I have file **recovery.cmdline**. Following are its content:  `quiet ramdisk_size=32768 root=/dev/ram0 init=/init vt.cur_default=1 elevator=deadline `  but when I added init=/bin/sh it was únable to boot .

Comment: Tak a look at this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64653&p=476555